# cannot start DetaiActivity from MainActivity

Tags: android

i have problem when i want start activity named "DetailActivity" when i click on item in listview

[that's my main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSyA1.png)

so when i Click on item in listview i should see DetailActivity. Previously DetailActivity is opened when fragment of DetailActivity is declared in a static way, but when i change it to a dynamic way (by calling getSupportFragment().beginTransaction().add(.....)),the DetailActiviy is no longer started.

that 's my errors in Log Cat:

```
09-24 11:01:37.986 9114-9114/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0f0080 (com.example.android.sunshine.app:id/weather_detail_container1) for fragment DetailActivityFragment{e479b98 #1 id=0x7f0f0080}
09-24 11:01:37.986 9114-9114/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
09-24 11:01:38.003 9114-9114/com.example.android.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.android.sunshine.app, PID: 9114
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0080 (com.example.android.sunshine.app:id/weather_detail_container1) for fragment DetailActivityFragment{e479b98 #1 id=0x7f0f0080}
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f0080 (com.example.android.sunshine.app:id/weather_detail_container1) for fragment DetailActivityFragment{e479b98 #1 id=0x7f0f0080}
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1326)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:554)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6997)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

the problem here is that i have declared id "weather_detail_container1" in layout of DetailActivity, but when i use this id for adding fragment dynamically, the activity couldn't recognize it.

The other thing is that i have declared this id in two layouts activity_detail1.xml (layout of DetailActivity) and activity_main.xml (layout of MainActivity for tablet).

activity_main.xml for tablet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:contentInsetLeft="16dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="16dp"
                app:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
                app:titleMarginStart="32dp"

                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
        <!--xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/container"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity"-->
        <!--android:background="@android:color/white"-->
        <!--tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"-->
        <!--&gt;-->

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity">


            <fragment android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment"
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"
                />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/weather_detail_container1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--</FrameLayout>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_detail1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:titleMarginStart="32dp"/>

                <!--<ImageView-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="24dp"-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="24dp"-->
                    <!--android:maxWidth="16dp"-->
                    <!--android:maxHeight="16dp"-->
                    <!--android:src="@drawable/sunshine_logo"-->
                    <!--android:gravity="left"-->
                    <!--/>-->

            <!--</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>-->

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
            <!--xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/fragment"-->
            <!--android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivityFragment"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />-->
        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/weather_detail_container1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bit of code in DetailActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
//        frame.setId(R.id.frameFragment);
//        setContentView(frame, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
//                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail1);
        if(savedInstanceState==null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.weather_detail_container1, new DetailActivityFragment());
            //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The LinearLayout inside your CoordinatorLayout occupies the entire screen and leaves no space for the FrameLayout (which is the container you are using) because you are using "match_parent" for both height and width. When Android searches for this view, it does not find anything and that is the stack trace that you are seeing.

To fix this, you should be splitting the screen in a manner that shows the FrameLayout i.e. the LinearLayout does not occupy the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

The error specified is:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id
>   0x7f0f0080
>   (com.example.android.sunshine.app:id/weather_detail_container1) for
>   fragment DetailActivityFragment{e479b98 #1 id=0x7f0f0080}

the view is not found!, i see that `DetailActivity` loads the layout `activity_detail1.xml`, but check if you are using other layout with the same name defined for certain orientation or density, for example:

[image]

probably one of them doesn´t contain `weather_detail_container1`

Comment: i noticed that layout-v21 include also activity_detail1.xml that doesn't contain id :weather_detail_container1,so i have deleted this file and directory,clean project, but this error is still occurred.

Comment: What message is displayed in your logCat?